# Probably of picking red ball from urn in two tries with 4 total balls all different colors without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Say the urn has 4 balls, 1 red, 1 black, 1 blue, 1 green.

I want to pick the red one and have two tries without replacement.

How would I calculate this probability?

Answer (score 3):

Sample space: choosing a pair of 2 balls.

Event: choosing the other ball (red must be chosen).

Answer: $\tfrac{3}{{4 \choose 2}}=\tfrac{1}{2}$

Another way to look at it: you permute all $4$ balls. The ones in places 1 & 2 were picked, the ones in 3 & 4 weren't. The red ball can have any place with equal probability, so the probability of having a good place is $\tfrac{2}{4}$.

Comment: Where do you get the 3 in the equation 3/4 choose 2? Number of balls minus number of balls desired?

Comment: Yes. The number of non-red balls.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, there are four balls, one red.  The probability of picking the red ball on the first pick is 1/4, the probability of any other color is 3/4.  If you don't get the red ball on the first pick there are three balls left, one red.  The probability of getting the red ball the second time is 3/4.  So the probability of getting a red ball with two picks is the probability of getting a red ball on the first pick or not getting a red ball on the first pick but getting a red ball on the second pick.  That is 1/4+ (3/4)(1/3)= 1/4+ 1/4= 1/2.